# Gmail filter for messages received within a time window

Tags: gmail-filters

We've set up a burglar alarm system that sends notification e-mails to a Gmail account.  The issue with the burglar alarm is that it is too sensitive, and sends multiple e-mails for the same "disturbance."  The message bodies aren't exactly the same.  These near-duplicates are sent inside a window of less than 30 seconds.

I'd like to use Gmail filters to delete near-duplicate messages that are grouped within that 30 second window.  A new message that is received outside of this window shouldn't be deleted because it's considered a separate disturbance.  Is this possible?  Much appreciated!

Comment: Not possible with Gmail filters alone. There are no time-based triggers.

Comment: You can create [time-based Gmail filters with Google Apps Script](http://www.johneday.com/422/time-based-gmail-filters-with-google-apps-script) but I'm not sure what the configuration would look like for your specific problem.

Comment: If you still need this, let me know and I can try making such a script for you. My email is 1na at inbox.com